# Is there any way to execute code once in a ASP.NET Web API REST service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, event-log

I have an ASP.NET Web API REST service and I would like to execute some code once when service is started only for first time, not each time a web api method is requested/invoked from my ASP.NET MVC application.

I would like to do this because I want to initialize an EventLog and then use it to create entries in the windows event viewer.

Is there some easy way to do it?

**UPDATE**:
As Jonhatan suggested in his answer I create a method within global.asax.cs:

**Global.asax.cs**:

```
namespace MyWebAPIApp
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public MyLog _myLog;

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
             // Here some stuff

             SetupEventLogging();
        }

        private void SetupEventLogging()
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MyWebApiLog"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyWebApiLog", "MyWebApiLogLog");
            }

            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
            eventLog.Source = "MyWebApiLog";
            eventLog.Log = "MyWebApiLog";
           
            _myLog = new MyLog(eventLog, "MyWebApiService");
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
namespace MyWebAPIApp.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        public void GetAll()
        {
            _myLog.Success("All records read");
        }
    }
}
```

But now if I create a global variable _myLog, how can I access this variable from all the methods in my Controller in order to do _myLog.Error(...) or _myLog.Success(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically do that in the `ApplicationStart` method in your global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        SetupLogging(); // do something in here / wire up your flavour of logging
    }
```

Often, the pattern will be:

1. set up your logging on app start - this is where you set up the database connection to store the logs, etc
2. call a static `logger.Write` method throughout your code whenever you want to write to log.

I use Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, but I think Serilog or Log4Net are 2 probably more common frameworks now.

So, in my global.asax.cs, the `SetupLogging()` method is:

```
    private static void SetupLogging()
    {

        var configurationSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
        DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory(configurationSource));

        var logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configurationSource);
        Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriterFactory.Create());

        var daysToKeepLogsInDb = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DaysToKeepLogsInDb"]);
        CustomLogger.PurgeLogs(daysToKeepLogsInDb); // only keep last 90 etc days of event logging in the db

        CustomLogger.Write("Application Starting", TraceEventType.Information);
    }
```

Basically just the things that the framework needs to 'get going', and a little custom cleanup. And then I have a `CustomLogger` class to help write entries the way I want, run a custom stored procedure to clean up old logs, etc:

```
 using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 
 namespace MyApplication.Helpers
 {
     public class CustomLogger
     {
         private static readonly ICollection<string> EmptyCategoriesList = new List<string>(0);
         private const string LogTitle = "MyApplication Name";
 
         public static void Write(object message)
         {
             Write(message, TraceEventType.Error);
         }
 
         public static void Write(object message, TraceEventType severity)
         {
             Logger.Write(message, EmptyCategoriesList, -1, 1, severity, LogTitle);
         }
 
         public static void PurgeLogs(int keepLastXDays)
         {
 
             var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyLoggingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 
             using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
             {
                 using (var command = new SqlCommand("PurgeLogs", con)) // custom stored procedure
                 {
                     var dateTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(keepLastXDays * -1);
 
                     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateTo", dateTo));
                     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@title", LogTitle));
 
                     con.Open();
                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     con.Close(); // technically not required because in using, but leaving in case this block gets copy-pasted out of here
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

And then, within my code (controller, helper, whatever), I write tot he log through the static method in the custom logger:

```
    public static void EndSession(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            Logon.DoLogoff(session);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            CustomLogger.Write(exception);
            throw new Exception("Error ending session.");
        }
    }
```

If you do this with dependency injection, it would (especially) allow you to swap out your logging framework more easily, and allow you to unit test a little more easily. But you would have to create another 'layer' between your application and the logger to abstract the relationship out a bit more. You should read up on dependency injection, as it is something that is often worth using.

Comment: ok, but in SetupLogging I should create a global variable in some way in order to all the methods in the controller can access to it for writting against the event log. See my update.

Comment: @Ralph You should really look into setting up a dependency injection, it's a bit manual to do in older tech like this, but fully worth it.

Comment: @DavidG It seems interesting. Could you put some code snippet?

Comment: @Ralph you don't typically need a global variable, so long as your logging methods are static. I'm putting some more details in my answer above

Comment: Ok, and Where is the best place within the web api project folder structure to put this CustomLogger class?

Comment: Ok I have done what you recommended and I have also used DI (Dependency Injection) in order to swap out my logging framework in a future. Now from my SetupLogging in my global.asax.cs I have this: EventViewerLogger evLogger = new EventViewerLogger(); MyLogger myLogger = new MyLogger(evLogger); As you can see, I inject evLogger to MyLogger class. Now how can I make myLogger available to the entire app (controllers, etc.) in order to I can perform myLogger.Write("blabla") ? using what Oleksii suggested, I mean putting myLogger as static into static class?

Answer (score 1):

> But now if I create a global variable _myLog, how can I access this variable from all the methods in my Controller in order to do _myLog.Error(...) or _myLog.Success(...)?

Make `_myLog` static and reference it `WebApiApplication._myLog` where `WebApiApplication` is application class defined in `global.asax.cs`.

I'd rather create some static class with MyLog static property:

```
public static class LogManager
{
    public static MyLog Logger;
}
```

And in `global.asax.cs` in `SetupEventLogging()` put

`LogManager.Logger = new MyLog(eventLog, "MyWebApiService");`